# Infinite set if derived set is non empty

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> Consider $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the usual topology. Let $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$. If $der(A)\ne\emptyset\implies A$ is infinite.

I'm really stuck with this problem. I tried to prove it by contradiction, so I get that $$C\subseteq B^\circ_\varepsilon(x) \cap A\neq\emptyset$$ is a finite, where $x\in der(A)$. Since $C$ is finite, it is also compact. But from here, I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $A$ is a finite set and $x$ is any point not in $A$ then  the ball of radius $r$ around $x$ has no points of $A$ if $0<r <\min \{\|x-a\|:a \in A\}$, so $x$ is not a  limit point of $A$. This means that a finite set $A$ has no limit points and its derived set is empty.

Comment: But where is the contradiction?

Comment: @RergisM I have edited.